# Inserting a dynamic header into multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I am using ***jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js and dynamicpage.js*** to load the content dynamically from the index page and therefore keeping the header in one file. However, the jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js is interfering with other jQuery in my content.

Is there a way to insert the header into the pages instead of inserting the content into the index page with the header?

please note I am using HTML5 / CSS and jQuery  (not php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to add code with JQuery, but I wouldn't recommend it because if the user turns off his javascript, you won't have a header.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script>

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){       
            $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="header"]').load("header.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
            }); 
            $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="footer"]').load("footer.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
            });  
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
```